# Javascript, mustache.js, how to

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am using mustache.js, to put my page together, and on an event i am catching a json object, which I save in a variable, the code looks like this:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "first": null,
            "second": "something",
            "third": "etc"
        }, {
            "first": null,
            "second": "something",
            "third": "etc"
        }, {
            "first": null,
            "second": "something",
            "third": "etc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I cant figure out what mustache structure to use on the template to show the data in a table. It seems the array is irregular shaped, I want to put it into a table. Any ideas? THX.

Comment: Looks quite regular: `{"first":null, "second":"something", "third":"etc"}` is one row, just normal usual mustache loop.

Comment: This object is perfectly regular, as @dfsq says. The object has a property called `result`, which is an array of three objects. Each child object has the same structure. Also, there is no such thing as a *"json object"*. How familiar are you with Javascript foundations?

Comment: Still learning javascript, im a html/php worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure looks quite normal and convenient for rendering in tabular view. Corresponding Mustache template could look something like this then:

```
<table>
{{#result}}
  <tr>
    <td>first: {{first}}</td>
    <td>second: {{second}}</td>
    <td>third: {{third}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/result}}
</table>
```

Check the documentation about [collectons](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#non-empty-lists) in Mustache.

Comment: The structure is good, but the "Mustache.render(template, view); " function seemes that it cant create the content of the page. Shall I use another Mustache function instead?

Comment: $("#templates2").load("../web/templates/templates.html #resultsdiv", function () {
                                    var template = document.getElementById('resultsdiv').innerHTML;
                                    var output = Mustache.render(template, view);
                                    $("#subresult").html(output);
                                });

Comment: Got it, I should not stringify the data, and it works nicely, THX for the help.